# jQuery AJAX request, succes executed but not applied in html

Tags: jquery, ajax

Well actually it does, but not what I would want.

```
 $('#progress', this).show();
 $('#txt', this).hide();

 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "./inviteAdminAddSample.php",
     data: {
         rev: rev,
         aid: aid,
         rating: rating
     },
     success: function(data) {
         $('#txt', this).html('Succesfully added!'); // ***
         $('#txt', this).show(); // ***
         $('#progress', this).hide(); // ***
     }
 });
```

Those 3 lines are not applied, but if I put them outside the succes (*infront of request for example*), it works.

Whats the deal here?

Comment: To be clear, console.log works so success is executed.

Comment: Why are you trying to scope `#txt` ID selectors anyway?  There should only be one element in the entire document with a given ID so `$("#txt")` should work fine, no need for the second argument.  If you're trying to work around duplicate IDs, then fix that problem first to make your HTML legal by switching to use a class name.

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the success callback is not referring to the element you want it to.

You could do the following:

```
var element = this;

$('#progress', element).show();
$('#txt', element).hide();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./inviteAdminAddSample.php",
    data: {
        rev: rev,
        aid: aid,
        rating: rating
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#txt', element).html('Succesfully added!'); // ***
        $('#txt', element).show(); // ***
        $('#progress', element).hide(); // ***
    }
});
```

But if you are using `id` attributes, I don't see the need to pass the second parameter to the `$()` function. If your `id` values are unique --- like they should be --- you should be able to use:

```
$('#progress').show();
$('#txt').hide();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./inviteAdminAddSample.php",
    data: {
        rev: rev,
        aid: aid,
        rating: rating
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#txt').html('Succesfully added!'); // ***
        $('#txt').show(); // ***
        $('#progress').hide(); // ***
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought its something related to "this" not being the same object in ajax call, but couldnt manage the right way to do it.

Thank you both!

About ID situation, it is like that I'm populating table with elements from db, and if I leave it as your second example, only first element of table is affected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The "this" inside your success callback refers to its own "this" and not the one you were going for.
Try this:

```
var self = this;
$('#progress',self ).show();
$('#txt',self ).hide();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./inviteAdminAddSample.php",
    data: {rev: rev, aid: aid, rating: rating},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#txt',self ).html('Succesfully added!'); // ***
        $('#txt',self ).show();                     // ***
        $('#progress',self ).hide();                // ***
    }
 });
```

This way you first save a reference to the "this" you want to target. You can than use that reference throught your code and it will always refer to what you intended.